# How to avoid navigation?

Tags: maui

I have 3 pages: Check, Login, Home.

I want Check to redirect the user to Login or Home depending on the conditions met.

It should redirect so that there is no navigation bar.

I watched JM's video. There's no explanation. The documentation is the same too. This can be seen in the Shell.Current.GoToAsync() example.

How should I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/pages?view=net-maui-7.0#disable-the-navigation-bar), you can hide the navigation bar on a page by doing

```
<ContentPage ...
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="false">
    ...
</ContentPage>
```